# how to delete an activation code after a user used once?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, activation-codes

when a new member is created , an registration confirmation email should be sent along with an activation code. once the user used the activation code. it shouldnt be valid anymore. I want to delete the activation code.

how to delete the activation code from database once its been used?

Comment: what's an `activation code`?
what kind of database is `the database`?

If you still need the activation codes later on, it may even be better not to delete them at all, but add a field that will let you flag them as inactive, or 'used'

Comment: i have edited my question.check it out

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that many questions are still unanswered, this answer is a concept-answer.

It can't 'just work'  like this, but it will give you an idea on how to handle this.

for this **example**, i'll assume you keep track of activation codes in a separate table of their own. 
*(which i have named `tblActivationCodes` in this example).*

Once the user 'activates', drop the corresponding activation code from the database table with a similar call :

this code will work only in the **`load`** event of a **`Page`** that takes `activationCode` as an inline request variable.

`http://www.mysite.com/activate.aspx?activationCode=12345-678-90`

```
string Code = Context.Request["activationCode"] as string;

// MAKE SURE TO PUT SOMETHING HERE
// THAT WILL PREVENT SQL INJECTION!

string Query = String.Format("DELETE FROM tblActivationCodes WHERE code='{0}';", Code );
```

Now, tell whatever database you're using, (you have not provided me with enough info for this) to execute that query.